# How to pass extra parameter in rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for

How I can get `redirect_id` from this form?

```
<%= form_for(@category) do |f| %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_id, :value=>5 %>
 <%= f.text_field :text %>
<% end %>
```

In controller I can get only `category` params in my `params` array.

Maybe because I'm using only this code to filter parameters in controller.

```
def panel_category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:text)
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following should work:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'redirect_id', 5 %>
```

See examples of using [`hidden_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag).